# jQuery Mobile changePage() not working in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application using Phonegap for Windows Phone 8.

I've used jQuery Mobile for interface design.

the `$.mobile.changePage()` is not working. The page is not being changed.

Is there any other way to change the page? Is there any other framework to design the interface for mobile?

```
$("#btnSearch").bind('click', function() {
    showSpinner();
    $.mobile.changePage("#pageSearch");
});
```

Comment: Ca you post the code that calls `$.mobile.changePage()`?

Comment: the code worked perfectly on Android.

Comment: Windows 8 Mobile version is not supported by jQuery Mobile up to current version, http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/. But your code is correct. Main problem is unsupported OS.

Comment: I think there's something that can help you. I remembered WP7 had a problem with a changepage function inside a phonegap app. Take a look at this link : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/5235 and google: jquery mobile changepage not working wp7

Comment: @Gajotres If Windows Phone 7.5-7.8 is supported, Windows Phone 8 definitely is as well (esp. because Windows 8 RT is supported, and both use a 'mobile-optimized' IE10). I'm sure it's not listed b/c they have no desire to QA it themselves

Comment: thanks brothers, thanks for your time. @Gajotres, i will check the github. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is the same as in WP7 described [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/5235).

**CHECK FOR PATH PROBLEM:**

```
if($.mobile.path.getLocation("x-wmapp1:/app/www/index.html") != "x-wmapp1:/app/www/index.html")
{
    console.log('there is path problem');
}
else
{
    console.log('everything is OK with paths');
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

As described in github, problem is path on WP7 differs from other platforms. Basically on WP7 getLocation prints relative paths with double slashes, which causes this issue at first place. To fix, open *jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js* and refactor following:

```
-        var uri = url ? this.parseUrl( url ) : location,
-          hash = this.parseUrl( url || location.href ).hash;
+        var uri = this.parseUrl( url || location.href ),
+          hash = uri.hash;
```

and:

```
-        return uri.protocol + "//" + uri.host + uri.pathname + uri.search + hash;
+        return uri.protocol + uri.doubleSlash + uri.host + uri.pathname + uri.search + hash;
```

After making this changes, check should display "everything is OK".

PS This is tested on WP7 and totally fixed my issue with $.mobile.changePage().

PS2 This issue is fixed at github version of jQuery, although I've just checked latest stable version([1.3.2](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js)) and unfortunately it is NOT fixed there.

Regards,

Hristo Todorov

Comment: Wowza, this fixed changePage for me in Windows Phone 8. Any chance this will be in 1.3.3 or os?

Answer (score 1):

I did have the paths problem mentioned in the answer above, but this didn't solve my problem. I discovered after a lot of trial and error that it was the protocol on the begining of the URL that was causing the problem.

A change page for "mypage.html" will send an Ajax request for

```
x-wmapp0://www/mypage.html
```

It needs to be just

```
www/mypage.html
```

I made a modifcation to the jQuery Mobile source to manipulate the string to cut off the protocol and now it works perfectly.

To apply the fix, in the *un-minified* jQuery Mobile js file, search for "$.ajax" and add the following just before it:

```
var parts = fileUrl.split("www/");
fileUrl = "www/" + parts[parts.length-1];
```

This actually removes "x-wmapp0://www/" and puts the "www/" back on again. Removing just "x-wmapp0://" does not always work because of the way jQuery Mobile works with urls, resulting in "www/www/..." in some cases.

This is confirmed to work with Cordova 3.1 and 3.3 with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2

Comment: Thank you so much this has been a huge pain for me! do I need to keep separate jQuery mobile versions for Windows Phone and iOs/Android (as I don't have the problem there)

Comment: I've been keeping a separate copy for mine.

Answer (score -1):

I think the method was renamed to "pagechange"

http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/09/08/jquery-mobile-beta-3-released/#upgrade

Comment: Negative. The event was renamed - the OP is asking about the changePage method which most certainly does still exist in JQM.