# IBM Worklight v 5.0.6 - Can't navigate multipages on Windows Phone 7.5 environment

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I'm having trouble with WP 7.5 application development in IBM Worklight v 5.0.6.
I used MultiPageApp Project from ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/wl_gs_all_samples.zip for my experiment.

There are many problems I had :

**First Problem**

I built WP 7.5 environment in worklight without editing the code. Then I run it in MS Visual Studio 2012 with Emulator 7.1 256MB. The problem is only the content of  from MultiPageApplication.html appeared.

**MultiPageApplication.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
        <title>MultiPageApplication</title>
        <link href="wlclient/css/wlclient.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="images/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
        <link href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
        <link href="css/MultiPageApplication.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>

        // Define WL namespace.

        var WL = WL ? WL : {};



        /**

         * WLClient configuration variables.

         * Values are injected by the deployer that packs the gadget.

         */

        WL.StaticAppProps = {
   "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "MultiPageApplication",
   "APP_SERVICES_URL": "http:\/\/169.254.17.188:8080\/apps\/services\/",
   "APP_VERSION": "1.0",
   "ENVIRONMENT": "windowsphone",
   "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
   "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "http:\/\/169.254.17.188:8080\/apps\/services\/api\/MultiPageApplication\/windowsphone\/"
};</script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="common/js/wljq.js"></script>
        <script src="common/js/base.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/messages.js"></script>
        <script src="common/js/wlcommon.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/diagnosticDialog.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/deviceAuthentication.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/window.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/worklight.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/wlclient.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/wlfragments.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/encryptedcache.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/jsonstore/jsonstore.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/challengeHandlers/antiXSRFChallengeHandler.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/challengeHandlers/authenticityChallengeHandler.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/challengeHandlers/deviceAuthAutoProvisioningChallengeHandler.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/challengeHandlers/deviceAuthNoProvisioningChallengeHandler.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/challengeHandlers/remoteDisableChallengeHandler.js"></script>
        <script src="wlclient/js/wlgap-wp7.js"></script><script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>

    </head>
    <body id="content" style="display: none">

        <div id="AppBody">
            <!-- This is static header, it will be shown always -->

            <div id="header">

                <h1>Multi page app</h1>

            </div>

            <!-- This is a placeholder for dynamic page content -->

            <div id="pagePort"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MultiPageApplication.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**MultiPageApplication.js**

```
var pagesHistory = [];
var currentPage = {};

function wlCommonInit(){

    $("#pagePort").load("pages/MainPage.html", function(){
        currentPage.init();
    });
}
```

At last I solve this by change the URL of jquery load API (manually in MS Visual Studio 2012) from

```
$("#pagePort").load("pages/MainPage.html",
```

to

```
$("#pagePort").load("default/pages/MainPage.html",
```

Although the code is working, another problem is

> Files in native/www are regenerated every time the application is
>   built, so any changes made to these files are lost.

what should I do to make the URL correctly generated?

**Second Problem**

When I want to navigate page from MainPage.html to Page1.html by pressing the "Load Page1" button,

the Page1.html won't load because the method 'init' in MultiPageApplication.js doesn't work. And I got this error from the output log in MS Visual Studio 2012:

```
Log:"Error in error callback: File564653615 = TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'init'"
```

I've tried changing the jQuery embedded in Worklight with jQueryMobile jquery-1.9.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js, but the same problem occured.

so, how should I fix this problem? Is it because the jQuery embedded in Worklight doesn't work in Visual Studio?

Thanks

Comment: The sample app you're using is meant for Worklight 6.0; Try with the sample for Worklight 5.0.6: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/previous-versions.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Sorry for my mistake, actually this question used the sample app for Worklight 5.0.6. I download it about 2 months ago and I've checked it again with your link. They're completely same. Any help? Thanks

Comment: @IdanAdar thanks for your response. Sorry for my mistake, actually this question used the sample app for Worklight 5.0.6. I download it about 2 months ago and I've checked it again with your link. They're completely same. Any help? Thanks

Comment: I've been looking at it today for a long time, no good solution yet.

Comment: @IdanAdar oh no that's not good. :(
Anyway thanks for your help.
Is upgrading the IBM Worklight version may solve the problem?

Comment: No... But try maybe with Windows Phone 8 instead of 7.5, we believe this is an issue with the Explorer version used in WP 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the solution described here: [jQuery Mobile changePage() not working in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248911/jquery-mobile-changepage-not-working-in-windows-phone)

Namely:
open *jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js* and refactor the following:

```
-        var uri = url ? this.parseUrl( url ) : location,
-          hash = this.parseUrl( url || location.href ).hash;
+        var uri = this.parseUrl( url || location.href ),
+          hash = uri.hash;
```

and:

```
-        return uri.protocol + "//" + uri.host + uri.pathname + uri.search + hash;
+        return uri.protocol + uri.doubleSlash + uri.host + uri.pathname + uri.search + hash;
```

Note that I only checked this with the **changePage** method, but hopefully this fixes the file location for everything, including what you are experiencing.

Note: Be sure to return the application to its original state.