# IBM Worklight 6.0 - WL.Client.reloadApp() not working in Windows Phone 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using Worklight 6.0.0 enterprise edition and currently building hybrid apps for android, BB, Windows Phone 8 and iOS.

We are currently getting the below error when invoking `WL.Client.reloadApp()` when clicking on a logout button. This works fine all OSs except for WP8.

> CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed ::
>   ///www/default/www/default/pages/www/default/pages/www/default/pages/www/default/pages/myaccount.html
>   ERROR: Exception in InvokeScriptCallback :: An unknown error has
>   occurred. Error: 80020006. ERROR: Exception in InvokeScriptCallback ::
>   An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006.

This is our logout function:

```
logout() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    $.mobile.changePage("../MainPage.html");
    $('#username').val('');
    $('#password').val('');
    $("#Footer").show();
    $("#ui_logoutlst").hide();
    $("#homeBt_menu").hide();
    $('ul#QuickLinks li').width('50%');
};
```

Comment: This looks less related to the reload and more related to that path there... can you expend more about the structure of your application (multipages?)?

Comment: Also explain more about your logout function; surely it doesn't only do a reload...

Comment: Thanks Idan for the reply, in logout function we are clearing the localstorage and redirecting the user to main page of the application as shown below. The issue occurs when the user navigates to a page other than the home page and clicks on the logout button                                        function logout() {
 window.localStorage.clear();
 $.mobile.changePage("../MainPage.html");
 $('#username').val('');
 $('#password').val('');
 $("#Footer").show();
 $("#ui_logoutlst").hide();
 $("#homeBt_menu").hide();
 $('ul#QuickLinks li').width('50%');
};

Comment: Can you try a reload outside of the logout function, does it work correctly? In other words: try to recreate the issue in small testcase app that you can share with us.

Comment: how can i share the test case app, where can i upload?

Comment: You can upload it to Dropbox. But please, try to recreate this in as  simple application as possible...

Comment: i have uploaded the sample app in drop box, please find the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtd24yaehizd5qj/WindowTestApp.zip

Comment: Please also see my answer. I believe that's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated April 8th, 2014*

I have used the [sample project you've provided](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5cipq7shbk36rsb/Windows8Sample.zip) in my previous answer.
Here's an updated version: [WindowsTestApp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/42g8tm7uk9fs09w/WindowsTestApp.zip)

What I've done:

1. Removed use of the `path` variable in `wlCommonInit()`.
2. Added the `changeHash: false` option to `$.mobile.changePage()`.

   For example: `$.mobile.changePage("Pages/MyAccount.html", { changeHash: false });`
3. In WindowTestApp.html

   Removed this line from the `HEAD` element:

   `<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>`
4. In js\jquery-1.10.2.js:

   Find

   > xhr.open(s.type, s.url, s.async);

   Change to

   > s.url = s.url.replace("x-wmapp0:///", "");
   >   xhr.open(s.type, s.url, s.async);

Step 3 is correct use of `changePage` in case of using `WL.Client.reloadApp()`.

Step 4 seems to be a bug in jQuery/jQuery Mobile specific to handling to file location in Windows Phone.

Comment: Am suspecting because of the step4 we are getting the below errors        The thread 0xc5c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Error:"Unable to get property '__hasPendings' of undefined or null reference file:x-wmapp0:/www/default/wlclient/js/worklight.js Line:1763"
The thread 0xc60 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

Comment: @Shireesh, This is not related to this question; the changes made in this question are to: 1) allow to use changePage in Windows Phone, and 2) fix incorrect applicative code. Please create a NEW testcase project to show this new error and open a NEW question. This question is resolved - please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the edited comments and question, the problem could be at the path used.

Take a look at the multi-page sample project provided in the [IBM Worklight Getting Started webpage](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/). It contains special handling for WP8 which you may need to apply to your logout function as well.

[Building a multi-page application training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf)
[Multi-page sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/BuildingMultiPageApplicationProject.zip)

- **See slides 8 and 9**
- Slide 8 talks about the implementation change below
- Slide 9 talks about a change you must perform in *jQuery Mobile*'s JS in order to make page navigation work.
- Since you are using jQuery Mobile, take a look at this question and its answer: [IBM Worklight v 5.0.6 - Can't navigate multipages on Windows Phone 7.5 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965560/ibm-worklight-v-5-0-6-cant-navigate-multipages-on-windows-phone-7-5-environme)

Note how the path is handled specifically for Windows Phone 8.
**common\main.js**:

```
var path = "";

function wlCommonInit(){
    // Special case for Windows Phone 8 only.
    if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Environment.WINDOWS_PHONE_8) {
        path = "/www/default/";
    }
   ...
   ...
}
```

You need to now do one of two things:

- account for the path for WP8
- alter jQuery Mobile's JS if you use that

Comment: Thanks Idan!! Please provide the sample code, mean while I have downloaded the sample project but did not find anything specific to Windows phone 8.0

Comment: @Shireesh, Look at the path handling in wlCommonInit. That's the code sample. See my updated answer with a code snippet.

Comment: hi Adar, the team has already worked with the above suggestion and it did not work, it still resulted in the same error. Could you please look at the sample app and let us know the mistake that team is doing. you need to test on windows 8 physical device https://www.dropbox.com/s/5cipq7shbk36rsb/Windows8Sample.zip

Comment: @Shireesh, did you change both the path used as well as the bundled jQuery Mobile? Also please do not confuse between WINDOWS 8 and Windows PHONE 8

Comment: could you let me know what needs to be changed in Jquery bundle. I think the team has changed the path as well as applied the below changes in Jquery bundle var parts = fileUrl.split("www/");
fileUrl = "www/" + parts[parts.length-1]; the above lines have been placed before $.ajax.

Comment: And FYI since the above changes (path as well as Jquery bundle changes) did not work, they have removed the Jquery bundle changes and tried with only path change but still the issue exists.

Comment: @Shireesh, see my new answer.