# jquery mobile $.mobile.changePage() Windows phone 8 not working Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

code Index.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="data">

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <button data-role="button" id="changePage">Pass parameters with changePage function</button>
        <a href="second.html"  data-role="button">Or through a basic link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and My js file

```
 $(document).on('tap', "#changePage",function () {     
              $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
    });
```

and the second.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="second">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Second Page
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
<div id="data"></div>
    <div data-role="button" id="clickBtn">click me</div>
    <div data-role="button" id="paqeBtn">change Page</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

All these files are packaged using PhoneGap/Cordova and run on the device.

Basically i am trying to load second.html into index.html page using $.mobile.changePage("second.html") on tap event by binding to the ID #changePage in my JS file.

This is perfectly working fine in

- Android phones
- Internet Explorer 9 and 10
- Webkit Browsers

But the problem is the above code is not working on Windows Phone 8

The device i am testing on is **Nokia Lumia 920**
Jquery framework used is

- jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js
- jquery-2.0.3.js

i also tried with $.ajax as dataType:"html" and $.load functions all these worked perfectly fine in other environment mentioned above except in Window Phone 8 (device mentioned above)

I also followed this

[StackOverflow solution for Window phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248911/jquery-mobile-changepage-not-working-in-windows-phone)

**nothing worked!!!!!**

Comment: use jquery 1.9.1 not 2.0.3. Also, use `vclick` instead of `tap`, its faster than tap.

Comment: no use... Omar still not working!!!

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/5235

Comment: hi Omar i modified as per the pull request difference in jquery mobile. Still didnt work... You can see the link **"StackOverflow solution for Window phones"**  i have posted the link in my question which suggest the same. --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/17831415/1848109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.href;
                            url = url.split('#').pop().split('?').pop();
                            url = url.replace(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),"second.html");
                            $.mobile.changePage(url, { reloadPage : false, changeHash : false });
```

I used the Jquery suggested by OMAR jquery 1.9.1. and but still need to parse the URL before passing it to mobile change page. The above code worked perfectly fine.

The above code still will not work for Jquery 2.0+, use the 1.9.x version instead!!
 -

**My suggestion is not to use jquery 2.0+ for Windows Phones**

It will not work for Window Phone's including Ajax call like $.ajax, $.load, $.get

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just the other day. changeHash must be set to false in `$.mobile.changePage('second.html', { reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });`

There is a similar issue on older android devices.

Answer (score 0):

What I just got to work is a bit similar to @conor answer.  Maybe try using the pages css id as a selector.

using jquery mobile 1.3

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

              $(".myinfo").on("tap", function(){
                                 $.mobile.changePage("#MyInfo", { transition: "none", reverse: false, changeHash: true});
                                   });
```

HTML:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="MyInfo">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
```

Link:

```
     <li><a href="#" data-icon="custom" class="myinfo">My Info</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nirus's solution worked like a charm on the following environment:

- jQuery 1.9.1
- jQM 1.3.2
- Phonegap 3.5.0-0.21.14
- Windows Phone 8.1

I hope that issue can be fixed in the near future by Phonegap's or jQM's team.

Comment: My solution works till 1.10.x dont ever use Jquery 2.0