# JQuery load() function cannot work on Windows Phone 8 application built on PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, plugins, cordova, windows-phone-8

I had an application built on **PhoneGap** that using **Html, CSS, Javascript** for front-end and **WCF Web Service** for back-end. My App has been released for **Android** and **iOS** version. Now I am going to port my application to **Windows Phone 8**, but I had an issue with `JQuery load()` function. It works well on Android and iOS, but on Windows Phone 8 it failed.

I tried to replace the `load()` function by `$.mobile.loadPage()` or `$.mobile.changePage()`, but both is failed and throwed an code exception from `readResourceAsText` function.

`readResourceAsText` function is one of methods of PhoneGap built in plugins. I don't know why the `JQuery loadPage()` function will call directly to PhoneGap Plugin.

Anyone who had experiences on this, please share me to find out the problem. I am very appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share your requirement so we can suggest you some alternative. What you want to execute from load function?

Comment: Hi Rupesh. In My Application, the Jquery load() function is being used to load an htm file into DIV element. And that function is used with very high frequency. e.g: when user click on the button, the popup will show up and the content of that popup is loaded by the specific htm file

Comment: $("#dvContentIPad").load(_uiDevicePath + "SetupWizard/" + "PopUpView.htm", function () {
                var intent = new SetupWizardIntent();
                intent.setContainerDivName("#SetupWizard_MainContent");
                $(intent.getContainerDivName()).load(_uiDevicePath + "SetupWizard/" + "CountryListView.htm");
            });

Comment: are you sure load function is not getting called? or load is getting called but there is some error on code inside load? did you tried putting a console or alert at top of load function?

Comment: hi Rupesh. The load() function was getting called, but it caused an code exception from readResourceAsText function as I said above. And I don't know why the JQuery function will directly call the PhoneGap plugin. It really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Jquery load itself will not call any phonegap function for sure. this is your code inside the function which is calling phonegap functions. So there is something wrong with your code nothing to do with jquery load function.

Comment: Yes, at first my thinking is exactly what you said. But when create an empty phonegap project, and put the only load() function code to run for test. Then it called the phoneGap plugin. So I am very sure about that.

Comment: you put load function code right? did you tried with empty load function. is it still giving same error?

Comment: I found that there was an bug on that version of PhoneGap. After upgrade to latest version, there is not that error anymore, but the load() function still cannot work and mobile.loadPage() fucntion also failed too.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19021987/1848109 for answer i have fixed this by a work arround

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was an bug on that version of PhoneGap. After upgrade to latest version, there is not that error anymore, but the load() function still cannot work and mobile.loadPage() function also failed too.