# jQuery Mobile changePage() not working in WP8.1

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

Hi I've spent a long time trying to get my jquery mobile (v1.4.5) and cordova (v5.3.1) app running on WP8.1. It runs fine on iOS and Android. I am aware of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248911/jquery-mobile-changepage-not-working-in-windows-phone), and the problem I'm having is not related to this, or any others on SO.

Changepage seems to get stuck on WP8.1 because it thinks my app is still in a page transitioning state. For some reason releaseTransitionLock is not being called when it should from a previous transition.

If I comment out the if(isPageTransitioning) check in the 'change' method then it works, but I presume this has negative side-effects elsewhere.

It's a multipage app where all the pages are divs in the same html doc and I'm running jQuery v2.0.3. My changepage syntax is this, and I've tried it with transition 'none' and a variety of other options:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#register", { transition: "slide" });
```

Has anyone observed this behaviour and come up with a diagnosis or fix?

Answer (score 0):

Use below method and it will work definitely

```
$.mobile.navigate("#register", {transition: "slide"});
```

Comment: Thanks for this sunil, I didn't know about the navigate method as an alternative to changePage. I've changed all my 'changePage' calls to 'navigate' and my app still works happily on iOS and Android, but still fails on WP8. I'm going to go into some deeper debugging session I think.

Comment: oh..ok..best luck..will ping you if found any solution..if you get solution please share the answer